# Is there a way to make gravity come from a different part of the screen using spriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Is there any way to change the default behavior of the gravity with the spritekit framework? Normally gravity pulls things towards the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to make it so that gravity could pull in a different direction?

Comment: sure, with scene.physicsWorld.gravity = CGPointMake(x,y) you can make gravity with any direction, where direction depends on values used for x,y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for gravity in SpriteKit is

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -9.8); //dx = 0, dy = -9.8
```

Which is what makes any object fall down towards the bottom of the screen.

Similarly, to make an object go in different directions, you can explicitly set in the initWithSize method

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(-9.8, 0.0); //Towards left
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(9.8, 0.0); //Towards right
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 9.8); //Upwards
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(9.8, 9.8); //Towards top-right corner
```

I hope you get the point by now.

NOTE: The default value is -9.8 as the natural force of gravity we experience in the real world is 9.8 m/sec/sec. You can vary this value to change the intensity of the gravity experienced by the nodes in the scene.

You also need to understand more about [CGVector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGVectorMake) and the [`gravity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsWorld/gravity) property of [SKPhysicsWorld](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html).